# Is there a reason why ('img').load doesn't work (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, image, load

I have a set of images that I wanted to load first before executing the next line of code. The code is like:

```
$('div.some_class img').load(function() {
    // do something to div.some_class img
});
```

However, the images do not load before executing the commands. When I try `(window).load` though, it works.

My question is, why doesn't `('div.some_class img').load` work? Or is it because I'm using a class selector which is the slowest way to select an element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to firefor images that already live in the browser's cache

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

https://gist.github.com/268257 - this is a jQuery plugin to check for all images loaded

I don't think that load checks for the image to have actually loaded as much as that the tag has loaded? I had the same problem so used the above plugin